# How to find "import name" of any package in Python?

Tags: python, namespaces, pypi, cheeseshop

I wonder if is there any reliable and consistant way to get a Python package's "import name" / namespace. For example;

**Package**; django-haystack
**Import name**; haystack

or

**Package**; ipython
**Import name**; IPython

So far I know, PyPi doesn't store that information that I've checked with PyPiXmlRpc.

I also tried to automate to download the package, extract it and dig the .egg-info but some packages doesn't have that folder at all.

Any help will be appreciated and will be used for a good-manner gadget :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that what you call a package here is not a package but a *distribution*. A distribution can contain zero or more modules or packages. That means there is no one-to-one mapping of distributions to packages.

I'm not sure there is a way to detect what modules and packages will be installed by a distribution, other than actually installing it and introspect filesystem changes for newly added packages, modules and pth files.

Comment: I understand. Major problem is the relation between a distribution and a package/packages as I see. But there must be an answer to my question. I will find the most reliable and consistent one and let you guyz know for sure.

Comment: after a long long researching period, i end up with your answer that any Python distribution may have one or more packages such as the package itself and let's say a test package next to as a simple example. Anyways, i was able to finish my experimental prototype (pydoc.net) and hopefully will provide some sort of API to cover this question consistently.. Thanks Wichert.

Answer (score 10):

## Wheels

I know this is an old question, but **wheel** packages have since been invented!  Since a **wheel** is simply a zip file that gets extracted into the lib/site-packages directory, an examination of the contents of the wheel archive can give you the top level imports.

```
>>> import zipfile
>>> zf = zipfile.ZipFile('setuptools-35.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl')
>>> top_level = set([x.split('/')[0] for x in zf.namelist()])
>>> # filter out the .dist-info directory
>>> top_level = [x for x in top_level if not x.endswith('.dist-info')]
>>> top_level 
['setuptools', 'pkg_resources', 'easy_install.py']
```

So setuptools actually gives you three top level imports!

## pip download

pip now has a download command, so you can simply run `pip download setuptools` (or whatever package you like) and then examine it.

## Reverse look up

As of Python 3.10, there is a convenience function that allows reverse look up (given the import name, what's the package).  The official [The official docs are here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#mapping-import-to-distribution-packages)

```
from importlib.metadata import packages_distributions
packages_distributions()
{'importlib_metadata': ['importlib-metadata'], 'yaml': ['PyYAML'],  ...}
```

For the forward lookup you could also simply build the reverse this dictionary.

Comment: As of 3.10, there's an easy way to do a reverse look-up, i.e. mapping import to distribution packages: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#mapping-import-to-distribution-packages

Comment: Thanks, @huyz !  I've updated my answer with this information.

Answer (score 5):

In principal, everything you need to get that information is in the `setup.py` that is supposed to be in every such package.  That information would roughly be the union of the packages, py_modules, ext_package and ext_modules of the Distribution object.  In fact, here's a little script that mocks out `distutils.core.setup` just for the purpose of getting that information.

```
import distutils.core
distutils.core._setup_stop_after = "config"
_real_setup = distutils.core.setup
def _fake_setup(*args, **kwargs):
    global dist
    dist = _real_setup(*args, **kwargs)

distutils.core.setup = _fake_setup

import sys
setup_file = sys.argv[1]
sys.argv[:] = sys.argv[1:]
import os.path
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(setup_file))

execfile(os.path.basename(setup_file))

cat = lambda *seq: sum((i for i in seq if i is not None), [])
pkgs = set(package.split('.')[0] for package
           in cat(dist.packages,
                  dist.py_modules,
                  [m.name for m in cat(dist.ext_modules)],
                  [m.name for m in cat(dist.ext_package)]))

print "\n".join(pkgs)
```

For many packages, this will work like a charm, but for a counterexample, see `numpy`,  It breaks because numpy *provides its own distutils*, and I can see no obvious way around it.

Comment: I didn't have chance to try, will do as soon as possible and feedback. thanks in advance!

Comment: yes it works for many package releases but as I understood it works in the modulefinder's logic that gives you all the modules had been used and you get the high-level namespace(s) out of it. Unfortunately, it gives more than one namespace if the release is using some other package such as test; check django-uni-form for example. I just modified your script a bit by the way; https://gist.github.com/1176645

Comment: And Python should make "import name" field required on PyPI! Can't be that painful... stucked.

Comment: Seriously... I've been racking my brain for a while on how to get the distribution name from the import name. There's just not a way currently. I had hoped that the `provides` key in `setup.py`would provide this. I had hoped to be able to query that through https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIXmlRpc, but no luck ):

Answer (score 2):

My project [johnnydep](https://github.com/wimglenn/johnnydep) has this feature:

```
>>> from johnnydep import JohnnyDist
>>> dist = JohnnyDist("django-haystack")
>>> dist.import_names
['haystack']
```

Do note that a distribution may provide multiple import names:

```
>>> JohnnyDist("setuptools").import_names
['pkg_resources', 'setuptools']
```

or none at all:

```
>>> JohnnyDist("bs4").import_names
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching lots of information, finally found the only thing which worked for me as expected. Example for `python-dotenv` package which has `dotenv` import name:

```
$ cat $(python -c "import pkg_resources; print(pkg_resources.get_distribution('python-dotenv').egg_info)")/top_level.txt
dotenv
```

*(taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54853084/3559739))*