# I installed a pip package, how to know the module name to import?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a python webpage **scraper** .

Some tutorial told me to use this package: BeautifulSoup. So I installed it using pip.

Then, in my script, I try to import BeautifulSoup as bs. But I was warned that no module named BeautifulSoup.

Is there a reliable way to get module name out of an installed package?

Comment: I'd imagine somewhere further down the tutorial they show you how to import and use it; e.g. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/. In the general case, I think this duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/q/7184375/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry for using this space for a question, but since you are a more experienced SO user, why posting this as a comment and not an answer? It seems `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` is really what OP wants.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar because their *actual question* is *"Is there a reliable way to get module name out of an installed package?"*, but I've run out of votes to close as a dupe.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh, I see, thanks. Yeah, it really seems a duplicate judging by the title.

Answer (score -1):

Try this `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Edit: Was already answered by @jonsharpe and @Vinícius Aguiar in the comments under the question.