# How to determine the modules available in a PyPI package

Tags: python, module, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

Given a PyPI package name, like [`PyYAML`](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/), how can one programmatically
determine the modules available within the package (distribution package) that could be imported?

## Detail

I'm not specifically interested in `PyYAML`, it's just a good example of a popular PyPI package which has a different
package name ([`PyYAML`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/0f64cbfa54b0b22dc7b776b7b98a7cd657e84d78/setup.py#L2))
from it's primary module name ([`yaml`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/0f64cbfa54b0b22dc7b776b7b98a7cd657e84d78/setup.py#L306))
such that you can't easily guess the module name from the package name.

I've seen other answers to questions that sound like this but are different, likely because of a naming collision

- [package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) meaning a python construct allowing for a collection of modules
- [package](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-distribution-package) meaning a "Distribution Package", an archive file that
  contains Python packages, modules, and other resource files that are used to distribute a Release.

My question is about the relationship between distribution packages and the modules within.

## Possible Solution Spaces

Areas that seem like they might be fruitful (but which I've not had success with yet) are :

- The [`pydoc.help`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pydoc.html#module-pydoc) function 
  (surfaced as the [`help` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#help))
  outputs a complete list of all *available* modules when called as `help('modules')`. This
  shows modules that have not been imported but could be. It outputs in a human readable form
  to stdout, and I've been unable to figure out how [the `pydoc` code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pydoc.py)
  enumerates the modules.

  - I could imagine calling this, gathering the module list, installing a new distribution package into a virtualenv with
    pip programatically, calling it again and diffing the results.
- Progamatically installing a distribution package with pip in order to

  - Iterate through elements of the python path to find modules

Comment: See also [How to find "import name" of any package in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7184375/674039)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My project [`johnnydep`](https://github.com/wimglenn/johnnydep) provides exactly this feature:

```
$ johnnydep --fields=import_names PyYAML
name    import_names
------  --------------
PyYAML  yaml
```

Note that some distributions export multiple top-level names, some distributions export none at all, and there is not necessarily any obvious relationship between the distribution name (used with a `pip install` command) and the package name (used with an `import` statement) - though it is a common convention for them to be matched.

For example, the popular project [`setuptools`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) exposes three top-level names:

```
$ johnnydep --fields=import_names setuptools 
name        import_names
----------  ---------------------------------------
setuptools  easy_install, pkg_resources, setuptools
```

API usage is via attribute access:

```
>>> from johnnydep.lib import JohnnyDist
>>> jdist = JohnnyDist("setuptools")
>>> jdist.import_names
['easy_install', 'pkg_resources', 'setuptools']
```

If you are interested to know *submodule names*, not top-level names, that's possible with stdlib [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.walk_packages), for example:

```
>>> import pkgutil, requests
>>> [name for finder, name, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(requests.__path__)]
['__version__',
 '_internal_utils',
 'adapters',
 'api',
 'auth',
 'certs',
 'compat',
 'cookies',
 'exceptions',
 'help',
 'hooks',
 'models',
 'packages',
 'sessions',
 'status_codes',
 'structures',
 'utils']
```

Comment: Yup, that works! Looking at your code for `johnnydep` it looks like the answer is to just brute force the thing. Create a temp directory, [download the package](https://github.com/wimglenn/johnnydep/blob/cb10eb4f8472e2df74e3c53f50e422e103d820f5/johnnydep/lib.py#L78-L83), [unzip it](https://github.com/wimglenn/johnnydep/blob/cb10eb4f8472e2df74e3c53f50e422e103d820f5/johnnydep/lib.py#L91) and [inspect the contents](https://github.com/wimglenn/johnnydep/blob/cb10eb4f8472e2df74e3c53f50e422e103d820f5/johnnydep/lib.py#L116-L117). Gets the job done, excellent. Thanks!